# Resfb OAUTH Token Never expires

Tags: restfb

What kind of permission do I need for the application that can read posts and comments from Facebook public pages.

I don't have a web or Mobile Application.

I want to run the code from my PC using restfb API.

Facebook have stopped my application from fetching this data - is it always mandatory to create an application and which asks user permission even for the public data ?

I don't need any personal Information, I only need posts and comments for general analysis

Answer (score 1):

For development purposes or for extracting certain data you can generate a user access token using the **Graph API Explorer** (selecting itself as the Application). It will expire in 1 hour, but it's enough if you want to download for example about 10,000 comments and posts from some public page (you should use the limit parameter at 100 to optimize your restricted access). For future and official use of your application it needs the feature "Page Public Content Access" that can be obtained with the Facebook review process.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs the feature "Page Public Content Access". You have to submit your app to the Facebook review.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: Much appreciated - will look into this and will ask for help if needed.